# Delay execution of jquery error function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the error function below to hide external images which do not seem to load. 
However images are hidden very easily and I think it is because the function executes to fast. Is there a way in Jquery to delay the function two seconds?

```
$(".display li img").error(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide("fast");
    pos3 = $(this).attr("id"); 
    reportrefcam();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably would do it from the other side. Waiting for the pages `load` event and then check all images. Checking means, look if the image has a `width` and `height`, if not its most likely broken.

```
$( window ).on('load', function() {
    $( '.display li img' ).each(function() {
        if( (!this.width || !this.height) ) {
            pos3 = $( this ).attr( 'id' ); 
            reportrefcam();

            $( this ).hide( 'fast' );
        }
    });
});
```

---

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vLC7U/

The window `load` event will eventually fire when all images + iframes on your entire side were loaded. So it's a save bet to say, if an image does not have a dimension at this point, its broken.

Comment: Interesting! How can I incorporate the part: reportrefcam();

Comment: @mark: just like that actually. I've updated the answer. However, what does that function do? Where does it needs to get called?

Comment: It wil flag the image-id in the database. So when there is no height or widht the trigger needs to be pulled.  Your solution can't be right ços it is always triggered.

Comment: @mark: so then, I've updated the answer again. You should like that better.

Comment: I have a feeling that the each.function is not working. The previous function did work. Any idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setTimeout` method

```
$(".display li img").error(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimout(function(){
        self.parent().parent().hide("fast");
        pos3 = self.attr("id"); 
        reportrefcam();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to delay the execution of a jQuery function or you can simply use setTimeout(). It's not clear what you need to delay, so i don't know what is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

In general java-script:

```
setTimeout("delayedFunctionName()",1000);
```

Here "delayedFunctionName()" is the function to be called and "1000" is the time delay in milliseconds.